How to run steam games with launch parameters in python?
I want to run steam game with launch parameters. How would i do this? Is there any library for it?
i tried to use
Subprocess.popen(f'Game/path/game.exe {Params}')

and etc, but got nothing or just regular game launch. But with steam client tools it works fine.

Try subprocess.run("something.exe --param1 --param2 --paramn", shell=True, check=True)

@x3l51 Probably actually avod shell=True and correspondingly refactor the first argument to a list. See also Actual meaning of shell=True in subprocess

Absolutely right!

I believe you would have to run Steam's launcher to start the game and pass parameters, not the app directly. You would just need to know the game's id. Shortcuts uses the "steam protocol" and looks like: steam://rungameid/{gameid} and  that "url" is passed directly to Steam. I assume you can also pass your game parameters as well. https://i.sstatic.net/kE1Oysab.png

You can use something like this:
subprocess.Popen(['C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steam.exe', '-applaunch', '1422450', '-console', '-novid'])

this command starts Deadlock with the developer console and without intro in my setup.
You must change the path with your steam.exe and update the 1422450 part with the game's AppID.

Although Windows is (generously or harebrainedly) tolerant of this error, the options should properly each be a separate string. That would then also allow this solution to work on adult platforms.

Makes sense. I update the answer.

Perhaps also nnte that Popen leaves you with a subprocess object you will need to manage yourself (at a minimum,wait for it at the end).
